# Documentation for ASP.NET Webforms jqGrid control?

Tags: jqgrid-asp.net

NOTE: I posted this question to the Trirand jqgrid support forum, but got no response.  So I'm posting here:

I can't for the life of me find the documentation of all the options available when configuring the `<trirand:JQGrid>` object.

Visual Studio iterates through the options with the Intellisense feature, but this doesn't tell me much, beyond giving me a super-long list of available config settings.

Am I missing something?  Most of my questions have to do with how to implement the config settings that I used to specify (without the ASP.NET Webforms control) when initializing the grid:

- Where do I configure things like altRows, altclass, etc.?
- Where do I configure rowNum, loadonce, pager settings, virtual scrolling, etc.?
- Where do I specify all the edit settings?
- What are the syntax options for specifying data formats, such as using DataFormatString="{0:d}" for dates...?

Note that I'm not posting to the forum seeking answers to these specific questions.  I'm trying to find where all these things are documented.  The Documentation section on the Trirand.net web site is very limited, and doesn't answer many of the lower-level-detail questions.  Particularly as compared to the documentation for the pure-javascript jqgrid widget, which is very thoroughly documented.

Maybe this level of detail is only available when you purchase the control?  That's fine, but I'll be a little gun-shy on purchasing if it's not clear that the product comes with thorough documentation...

Please advise...

Comment: Thanks, Chad, but I'm looking for the documentation for the paid jqgrid-asp.net control, which includes many server-side configuration options, which are not covered in the wiki documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

http://www.trirand.net/documentation/aspnet/index.htm

Apologies, I see you've already mentioned their site - I'll leave the above URL for reference though.